# Telerik MVC, Combobox changing the CSS of an item

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, combobox, telerik-mvc

My ASP.NET MVC-3 application is using the [previous version](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/telerik-mvc-extensions-resources.aspx) of [Telerik MVC Extensions combobox](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox). I am trying to change the style of an item in the list.

Here is the model:

```
public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool DisplayBold { get; set; }
        public string Value
        {
            get
            {
                return string.Format("{0}|{1}", this.Id, this.DisplayBold.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

The Controller:

```
var people = new List<Person>();
people.Add(new Person { Id = 1, Name = "John Doe", DisplayBold = true });
people.Add(new Person { Id = 2, Name = "Jayne Doe", DisplayBold = false });
ViewData["people"] = people;
return View();
```

The Combobox:

```
<% Html.Telerik().ComboBox()
   .Name("ComboBox")
           .BindTo(new SelectList((IEnumerable<Person>)ViewData["people"], "Id", "Name"))
           .ClientEvents(events => events
        .OnChange("ComboBox_onChange")
        .OnLoad("ComboBox_onLoad")
        .OnOpen("ComboBox_OnOpen"))
    .Render();
%>
```

I tried the following and it did change the first item:

```
var item = combobox.dropDown.$items.first();
item.addClass('test');
```

However when I tried to change the CSS when it is Ture:

```
var combobox = $(this).data('tComboBox');
$.each(combobox.dropDown.$items, function (idx, item) {
    if (combobox.data[idx].Value.split('|')[1] == 'True') {
        alert(item);
        $(item).addClass('test');

    }
});
```

It did not work!

Comment: It throws the DoesNotWorkException?

Comment: I don't get errors, just the style does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is the version after user373721 marked this as answered

While i was rewriting [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/673dad4e-d86d-4947-bff5-1c54743906dc/view-source) and browsing the forums user373721 marked [my old revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/673dad4e-d86d-4947-bff5-1c54743906dc/view-source) as answered.

I am sorry i [searched the forum of telerik](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/search.aspx?rtf=Forum&fid=358&start=160&sid=1&q=ComboBox()%2bBindTo%2b) to see how you could hook into the databinding to influence the [css](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/search.aspx?rtf=Forum&fid=554&start=0&sid=1&q=setting%2bcss%2bclass%2bof%2bcombobox%2bitem). I could not find a good match to your problem.

One muddy workaround (getting desperated here) could be to add html to the names that should be displayed bold:

```
public class Person
{
    public string NameText { get; }
    {
        get
        {
            if(this.DisplayBold) {
                 return "<b>" + this.Name + "</b>";
            } else
                 return this.Name; 
        }
    }
}
```

So instead of binding to Name you would bind to NameText. 
You may need to take care of html-conversion.

In [my last search](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/search.aspx?rtf=Forum&fid=554&start=0&sid=1&q=custom%2bcss) i found [a post that may help](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/combobox/feature-request-combobox-item-image-icons-custom-css.aspx). And now i found [a post that could be from you](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/combobox/custom-attributes-on-dropdownlist-items.aspx)

- By the way in the forums i have read  that there were several bug
  fixes that could be important for your goal. 
  **Which telerik mvc-release are you using?**

Comment: My first answer (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nDS3S/2/) uses the new version of telerik mvc. Since the OP uses the previous version i voted to delete my first post.

Comment: I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nDS3S/16/
This works for the current mvc-telerik-version (kendo)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time and providing a complete solution.  I just have two questions; on the server side, is HtmlAttributes related to each item?  On the clinet side, where theUlList is refrenced?  Thanks again for pointing me to the right direction.

Comment: The UIList is a placeholder; telerik stores the combobox-items in an ul list. After taking another look at the online demo i noticed that there is no easy way to get the ul-list: `var ulList = $('ul.t-reset');` returns several list.

I am afraid the client side will be a stony road. Can you use the server side binding?

HtmlAttribute is not related to each person. Upon binding you would need to return the displayBold value of each person that is bound to the combobox and set the style based on the return value from the method getBold.

Comment: Thank you for your support, I will try the server side binding.

Comment: I will try it, it is better to have control over the model than using Javascript.  I am using 2012.2.607 Telerik version.  I was trying a differnt approach using combobox.dropDown.$items[1].addClass('test');
Just posted new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556524/combobox-item-style.  Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution to set style with the new mvc-telerik extensions (kendo)

Hi based on the example at [telerik mvc comboBox usage](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/index.html) i used a template approach. At  jsfiddle you can find  [a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/nDS3S/16/) for the new telerik mvc extension (kendo).

Use of template to set style based on the underlying datasource:

```
<script id="template" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
  # if (data.displayBold) { #
    <span style="font-weight: bolder;">${ data.name }</span>
  # } else { #
    <span style="font-weight: normal;">${ data.name }</span>
  # } #
</script>
```

On document.ready bind the combobox:

```
    // use of templates
    $("#titles").kendoComboBox({
         dataTextField: "name",
         dataValueField: "Id",
         // define custom template
         template: kendo.template($("#template").html()),
         dataSource: musicians
                });
```

The dataSource is an array of objects similar to your person class:

```
var musicians= [{ id: 1, name: "Melody Gardot", displayBold: true }
 , { id: 2, name: "Lynn Withers", displayBold: false }
 , { id: 3, name: "Blue Ray", displayBold: true }    
 , { id: 4, name: "Club de Belugas", displayBold: true }    
 , { id: 5, name: "Mizzy Li", displayBold: false }    
];
```

hth

Comment: Thank you so much, I have edited my question to include all compoents.  I am still using the Old Telerik MVC Exts.