# Combobox item style

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, combobox, telerik, telerik-mvc

my project is asp.net MVC, using Telerik MVC combobox.  I can change the sytle of the first item if I use:

```
var item = combobox.dropDown.$items.first();
item.addClass('test');
```

Or change all items, using:

```
combobox.dropDown.$items.addClass('test');
```

But I need to change just specific items (based on a model), I tried:

```
combobox.dropDown.$items[1].addClass('test');
```

I get this error:
 `Object doesn't support property or method 'addClass`'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a jQuery object, you should replace:

```
combobox.dropDown.$items[1].addClass('test');
```

With:

```
combobox.dropDown.$items.eq(1).addClass('test');
```

`$items[1]` gives you the DOM object which doesn't  have the jQuery `addClass` function.
`$items.eq(1)` gives you the jQuery object which has the jQuery `addClass` function.